# How to make this unnamed function to general function that we can just call?

Tags: javascript, function

This is the script :

```
 $(function(){
  // Set up the number formatting.
  $('#price').on('change',function(){
    console.log();
    var val = $('#price').val();
  });

  $('#price').change(function(){
    console.log();
  });
  $('#price').number( true, 5 );        
});
```

Can it be general function that can be called whenever needed ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the function?

Answer (score 0):

Of course:

```
function setupPriceChange() {
    // Set up the number formatting.
    $('#price').on('change',function(){
        console.log();
        var val = $('#price').val();
    });

    $('#price').change(function(){
        console.log();
    });
    $('#price').number( true, 5 );
}

// from somewhere else in your script:

setupPriceChange();
```

You can name the function however you like. You can find a detailed explanation on JS functions on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor the code to hold the function in a variable, and call that variable when ever you want those scripts to execute. Like below

```
    var generalFunction = function(){  // Or general syntax function generalFunction(){
      // Set up the number formatting.
      $('#price').on('change',function(){
        console.log();
        var val = $('#price').val();
      });

      $('#price').change(function(){
        console.log();
      });
      $('#price').number( true, 5 );        
    }

    $(function(){
      generalFunction(); // once on document ready
    });
```

With this you just have to do `generalFunction();` when ever you want to execute those scripts.

Comment: `$(generalFunction)` no need to wrap it in a function, you can just pass it directly by reference.

Comment: It was meant to execute on `document.ready` that is what the OP has at the moment.

Comment: What @synthet1c means is that `$(generalFunction);` and `$(function() { generalFunction(); });` do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelGeary oh!! so does that mean `$(generalFunction)` executes the function `generalFunction` on `document.ready` ? I didnt know this.. Can you confirm'

Comment: Yes. Look closely and you'll see that this is also why the longer form works the way it does: either way, you are passing a function into the `$(...)` function.

Comment: @MichaelGeary yes now I see that.. :) Thanks ... But still it confuses me on the eye with that syntax.. i need to get used to it..

Comment: Another way to look at it... you could have written the longer version like this: `function readyFunction() { generalFunction(); }; $(readyFunction);`. Now it may be more apparent how it works.

Comment: @MichaelGeary yes I get it.. thanks that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

$(function(){}); is $(document).ready(function(){}); to change that to a named function it can be replaced as  the following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(Init);

function Init(){
alert("hello");  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and your code can be changed as this following snippet

```js
$(function(){
  // Set up the number formatting.
  $('#price').on('change',priceChange);      
});

function priceChange(){
   console.log();
    var val = $('#price').val();
}
```